# Making font size relative to screen width without repetition in CSS

Tags: html, css, font-size

In my webpage I want my fonts to have font sizes according to the width of the page. Currently I'm using `@media screen and (max-width: blah px)` to adjust to the screen size, but when I use it for every 100px it gets really long, and it seems like there must be a better way to do this.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1500px) {
    #todayDate, #cosmicDate, #cosmicdatelabel{
        font-size: 70px;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1400px) {
    #todayDate, #cosmicDate, #cosmicdatelabel{
        font-size: 65px;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1300px) {
    #todayDate, #cosmicDate, #cosmicdatelabel{
        font-size: 60px;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    #todayDate, #cosmicDate, #cosmicdatelabel{
        font-size: 55px;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1100px) {
    #todayDate, #cosmicDate, #cosmicdatelabel{
        font-size: 50px;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    #todayDate, #cosmicDate, #cosmicdatelabel{
        font-size: 45px;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    #todayDate, #cosmicDate, #cosmicdatelabel{
        font-size: 40px;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    #todayDate, #cosmicDate, #cosmicdatelabel{
        font-size: 35px;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    #todayDate, #cosmicDate, #cosmicdatelabel{
        font-size: 30px;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #todayDate, #cosmicDate, #cosmicdatelabel{
        font-size: 35px;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    #todayDate, #cosmicDate, #cosmicdatelabel{
        font-size: 20px;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    #todayDate, #cosmicDate, #cosmicdatelabel{
        font-size: 15px;
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? Or do I have to use this many repetitions to achieve this??

Comment: You could calculate the font-size based on the width by some JavaScript.

Comment: Maybe look into [Viewport-percentage lengths](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths) …

Comment: I don't know of a CSS only way to do this, but there is a jQuery plugin for this purpose called [FitText](http://fittextjs.com/).